# Invalid DataSource attribute. Either DataSourceSettingName or ConnectionString and TableName must be specified and cannot be empty

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Am Trying to run an Automation Script, The Build is successful but the script fails with below error when trying to run.

**Input File Name:** Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestData>
  <Environment>GE1</Environment>
  <URL>ApplicationURL</URL>
  <DCN>1060352</DCN>
  <TaxExceptDCN></TaxExceptDCN>
  <DOMS>100013010</DOMS>
  <Role>DHS - Order Processor Mexico</Role>
  <OPRole>DHS - APOS Sales Manager Mexico</OPRole>
  <Buid>Mexico</Buid>
</TestData>
```

**In My Test**

`[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\Input.xml", "TestData", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]`

I have the Set Properties of in Input.xml as "Copy Always"

But still am facing issue in running the script.

Error:

**Invalid DataSource attribute. Either DataSourceSettingName or ConnectionString and TableName must be specified and cannot be empty.**

Can you please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I'm having the same problem currently.